# Shorthand for declaring a boolean value in bash

Tags: bash, shell, testing

Say I have this bash function:

```
foobar_force(){
  foorbar "$@" --force
}

foobar () {
   local is_force=$(test "$2" == "--force");
}
```

I am looking for two things - I would like to only test if the last argument is "--force" not just the second argument, if possible.

Also I am looking for some shorthand I can use to declare `is_force` as true or false.

I guess the only way I know how to do that is to use:

```
if [[ "$2" == "--force" ]]; then
 local is_force="yes" ;
fi
```

Comment: `[[ "$2" == "--force" ]] && local is_force="yes"`?

Comment: thanks what about just getting the last arg?

Comment: I guess bash doesn't have booleans right, so a string "yes" is good

Comment: In a modern bash, `${@: -1}` is the last argument.

Comment: A slight modification to @Cyrus’s contribution would be: `is_force=$( [[ "$2" == "--force" ]] && echo true || echo false )`

Comment: Why does `--force` have to be the *last* argument? `foobar` should simply look at *all* its arguments, set `is_force` it sees `--force` along the way, *then* proceed with the rest of the function.

Comment: @chepner you're right, I agree that bash/command line programs should be agnostic about order of arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
$ cat example.sh 

foobar () {
   [[ "${@: -1}" == "--force" ]] && local is_force="true" || local is_force="false";
}

foobar_force(){
  foobar "$@" --force
}
```